# JavaScript, Node.JS : Wait until copying a folder, then edit files in it (async, await)

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs-extra

I am building a node.js program that copies a directory then edits the files in it. However, my code tries to edit the files before copying is done. I have tried adding `await` to the code, but could not solve the problem. The following is my code.

```
    const srcDir = `./old_dir`
    const destDir = `./new_dir`
    await fse.copy(srcDir, destDir, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err
    })

    // call the function that edits the files
    await create_page({info: queryparams})
```

I want to wait until copying the directory is complete, then call create_page. However, the following code calls create_page before copying the directory is done, which causes error of "no such file or directory".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra):

> All async methods will return a promise if the callback isn't passed.

Since you passed a callback to the `copy` method, the `await` will not "wait" for the async action to complete. So drop the callback argument:

```
const srcDir = `./old_dir`
const destDir = `./new_dir`
await fse.copy(srcDir, destDir);
// call the function that edits the files
await create_page({info: queryparams})
```

If you want anything else than re-throwing errors when they occur, then wrap the `await` code in a `try...catch` block.

Comment: Realized that I had a fundamental problems. Thank you for the advise. Problem solved! I thought passing a callback to methods is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an alternative to @trincot answer, you can also use `copySync(src, dest[, options])` method which waits till the task is complete.